# Django Ajax 403 only when Posting from custom localhost url

Tags: ajax, django, xmlhttprequest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I followed all the instructions to get Ajax working properly with Django (ajaxSetup to add the X-CSRFToken header on every request, etc) and that part now works fine.

**I'm using django-rest-framework, django-allauth and rest-auth**

I'm now trying to test Facebook login with DRF, since Facebook doesn't allow for localhost to be a registered app I edited ~/etc/host and added local.test.com as an alias for 127.0.0.1. Now whenever I try to post to Django I get 403 forbidden again. I think it may have something to do with the *Request URL* and the *Remote Address* being different, but I don't really know what to do with it.

[image]

Since I'm not sure where the problem is I think it makes more sense to just share the link to the project on github: https://github.com/Sebastiansc/Sauti

**What can I do to allow POST Ajax requests coming from local.test.com to work?**

Answer (score 1):

try with @csrf_exempt

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def your_view(request):
    print "fff"
    print "do your things..."
```